# JS Nested Ternary with Multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

Essentially I have the following issue:

```
if condition A & B are true ->. do thing A
if only condition A is true -> do thing B 
else -> do thing C
```

I tried this :

```
const myThing = conditionA ? conditionB ? thingA :
conditionA ? thingB : thingC;
```

It doesn't like the syntax but I am not sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: `condition A & B are true` that's `conditionA && conditionB ? thingA ` not `conditionA ? conditionB ? thingA`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    const myThing = (conditionA && conditionB) ? thingA : (conditionA) ? thingB : thingC;
```

the same as:

```
if(conditionA && conditionB){
   thingA
}
else if(conditionA){
   thingB
} else {
   thingC
}
```

Comment: How is it JS Nested Ternary with Multiple conditions?

Answer (score 2):

You've already written out the logic with `if`/`else`, so why not do that in an IIFE? It'll be more readable than using the conditional operator:

```
const myThing = (() => {
  if (conditionA && conditionB) {
    return thingA;
  } else if (conditionA) {
    return thingB;
  } else {
  return thingC;
  }
})();
```

You could also put it into a standalone function:

```
const getThing = (conditionA, conditionB, conditionC) => {
  if (conditionA && conditionB) {
    return thingA;
  } else if (conditionA) {
    return thingB;
  } else {
  return thingC;
  }
};
const myThing = getThing(conditionA, conditionB, conditionC);
```

Rather than repeating the `conditionA` test, you could test for its *negation* initially to make it a bit simpler:

```
const getThing = (conditionA, conditionB, conditionC) => {
  if (!conditionA) {
    return thingC;
  } else if (conditionB) {
    return thingB;
  } else {
    return thingA;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
const myThing = conditionA?(conditionB?thingA:thingB):thingC;
```

Hope it helps.

The issue with your code is that you ternary operation require 2 expressions one if the condition is true and other if the condition is false But in your code false condition is not mentioned for given:

```
conditionA ? thingB
```

part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually meant to write there seems to be

```
const myThing = conditionA ? conditionB ? thingA : thingB : thingC;
```

However I do *not* recommend writing this as it's a lot harder to read *and write* as you already experienced. I'm adding this just as an explanation of how conditional operators work and *hopefully* to demonstrate that you shouldn't be using them for anything remotely complex. I find very limited application for the conditional in general and wouldn't miss it if it was never used. [Use `if/else` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61135244/).

For clarity, that expression resolves like this:

```
const myThing = conditionA ? (conditionB ? thingA : thingB) : thingC;
```

- if `conditionA` is `true` - evaluate the second conditional operator

  - if `conditionB` is `true` - return `thingA`
  - if `conditionB` is `false` - return `thingB`
- if `conditionA` is `false` - return `thingC`

This plays on boolean logic combination where

```
if (A) {
  if (B) {}
}
```

is equivalent to combining the two conditions via AND

```
if (A && B) ()
```

However, nesting the expressions makes it a lot harder to understand what is happening because you need to mentally map *the entire* expression in order to understand it. Compare these two

```
const x = A ? B ? C ? "one" : "two" : "three" : "four";
```

and

```
if (A && B && C) return "one";
if (A && B) return "two";
if (A) return "three";

return "four"
```

With the latter you need to only understand one expression at a time to find out what's being returned, with the former you need all of them.